# what does padding_idx do in nn.embeddings()

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm learning pytorch and
I'm wondering what does the `padding_idx` attribute do in `torch.nn.Embedding(n1, d1, padding_idx=0)`?
I have looked everywhere and couldn't find something I can get. 
Can you show example to illustrate this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=embedding#torch.nn.Embedding), `padding_idx` pads the output with the embedding vector at `padding_idx` (initialized to zeros) whenever it encounters the index.

What this means is that wherever you have an item equal to `padding_idx`, the output of the embedding layer at that index will be all zeros.

Here is an example:
Let us say you have word embeddings of 1000 words, each 50-dimensional ie `num_embeddingss=1000`, `embedding_dim=50`. Then `torch.nn.Embedding` works like a lookup table (lookup table is trainable though):

```
emb_layer = torch.nn.Embedding(1000,50)
x = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
y = emb_layer(x)
```

`y` will be a tensor of shape 2x4x50. I hope this part is clear to you.

Now if I specify `padding_idx=2`, ie

```
emb_layer = torch.nn.Embedding(1000,50, padding_idx=2)
x = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
y = emb_layer(x)
```

then output will still be 2x4x50 but the 50-dim vector at (1,2)  and (2,3) will be all zeros since `x[1,2]` and `x[2,3]` values are 2 which is equal to the `padding_idx`.
You can think of it as 3rd word in the lookup table (since lookup table would be 0-indexed) is not being used for training.

Comment: Did you meana x[0,1] and x[1,2] will all be zeros?

Comment: I think he refers to y[0,1,2] and y[1,2,3] to be zero vectors of size 50.

Comment: @Bhashithe Yes. I thought of that as a matrix and read it as 1-indexed (as humans do). I have edited the answer to make both 0-indexed now.

Comment: Does it mean padding_idx masks the input?

Answer (score 25):

`padding_idx` is indeed quite badly described in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Embedding).

Basically, it specifies which index passed during call will mean "zero vector" (which is quite often used in NLP in case some token is missing). By default no index will mean "zero vector", as you can see in the example below:

```
import torch

embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(10, 3)
input = torch.LongTensor([[0, 1, 0, 5]])
print(embedding(input))
```

Will give you:

```
tensor([[[ 0.1280, -1.1390, -2.5007],
         [ 0.3617, -0.9280,  1.2894],
         [ 0.1280, -1.1390, -2.5007],
         [-1.3135, -0.0229,  0.2451]]], grad_fn=<EmbeddingBackward>)
```

If you specify `padding_idx=0` every `input` where the value is equal to `0` (so zero-th and second row) will be `zero-ed` out like this (code: `embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(10, 3, padding_idx=0)`):

```
tensor([[[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [-0.4448, -0.2076,  1.1575],
         [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 1.3602, -0.6299, -0.5809]]], grad_fn=<EmbeddingBackward>
```

If you were to specify `padding_idx=5` last row would be full of zeros etc.